# list of users that are in an OU AND a memberOf a certain sec group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have 2 lists, one that has all members of a certain OU.  Another that lists all the Members of a sec group.  I'd like to compare the two lists and compile one list of users that are in both.  Anyone nudge me in the right direction?

```
get-adgroupmember [sec group] | FT Name | out-file "path\file.csv"
get-aduser -filter * searchbase "Conical path of OU" | FT Name | out-file "path\file.csv"
```

Throwing these two commands into variables[arrays] and using the compare-object really doesn't tell me much.  This is a snippet of output from that

InputObject                                                                      SideIndicator                                                                                       -------------
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData                                       ==
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData                                        ==
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData                                       ==
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData                                       ==
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData                                       ==
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData                                       ==
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData                                       ==
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData                                       ==
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData                                       ==
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData                                       ==
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData                                       ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need that second search at all.  The OU location of the users is implicit in their distinguished names:

```
$ou = 'ou=Execs,ou=Operations,dc=domain,dc=tld'

get-adgroupmember [sec group] |
 where $_.distinguishedname -like "*$ou"
```